# UICollectionViewCells are resetting their size after being rearranged

Tags: swift, ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I've got a UICollectionView of cells with labels on them, and I would like to be able to reorder them by dragging and dropping.

The cells are sized with estimatedItemSize because I want them to be all different sizes, depending on the size of the text in the cell. I can get that to appear fine. However once I use **collectionView.moveItemAtIndexPath** the cells seem to resort to a default size.

Resetting the collectionView's flow layout straight after the move doesn't fix it either.

In **viewDidLoad**

```
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

The **UIPanGestureRecognizer** that reorders the text

```
func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let locationPoint = sender.locationInView(collectionView)
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {

        if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(locationPoint)? {

            if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.bounds.size)
                cell.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
                let cellImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

                movingCellImage = UIImageView(image: cellImage)
                movingCellImage.center = locationPoint
                movingCellImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2)
                collectionView.addSubview(movingCellImage)
                cell.alpha = 0
                movingCellOriginalIndexPath = indexPath

            }

        }

    } else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed {
        movingCellImage.center = locationPoint

    } else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

        if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(locationPoint)? {

            let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(movingCellOriginalIndexPath)
            collectionView.moveItemAtIndexPath(movingCellOriginalIndexPath, toIndexPath: indexPath)
            cell?.alpha = 1

        }

        movingCellImage.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

[image: Before and after moving a UICollectionViewCell, having moved the second cell to the first]

Comment: There's a property close to the bottom of a UILabel in Storyboards called "Autoresize Subviews". If I'm not mistaken, that makes UILabels call "sizeToFit" which seems to be your problem. Non of this is tested, so I'm not making it an answer. So if you turn that option off, it might solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading with animation seems to solve the issue.
**But** previous layout remains for a moment... You may need to create a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` instead of using `estimatedSize`.

```
if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(locationPoint)? {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(movingCellOriginalIndexPath)
    collectionView.moveItemAtIndexPath(movingCellOriginalIndexPath, toIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell?.alpha = 1

    collectionView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0)) // not reloadData
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

As you point out, the key is `-collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`.

- don't set `estimatedSize` to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`
- calculate each cell size in the delegate method above

like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let str = data[indexPath.item] // string to show in label

    // calculate size. you can use -boundingRectWithSize: as well
    var txtsize = (str as NSString).sizeWithAttributes([ NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)]) // specify label's font
    txtsize.width += 10 // add margin if necessary
    txtsize.height = 100 // calculated text height or any value you want

    return txtsize
}
```

Comment: Calling reloadSections does put the cells back to their small/tight versions with estimatedSize. Thanks for that. You're right though, previous layout briefly appears and looks horrible. Would you know a way to use UICollectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath to still be different heights and widths for each different piece of text?

Comment: This update seems like it is going to solve all my problems, however i'm having an issue with what txtsize is returning. For instance the word "all" gives a width of NaN. If i force str to be "HELLO" the width is only 6.953, and that's after the margin. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: what kind of font do you specify to calculate string-size? the font(and size) should be the same as label's one. in my environment, size(without margin) of "all" is (16.032,19.088) and "HELLO" is (51.84,19.088) with systemFont(16pt).

Comment: I'm using your code, and have made my cell in IB use the same System size 16 that you specified in code. I've tried it in two different collectionViews, (though both in the same project). In IB the label simple says "label" and is using auto layout, 10 from the top, right, bottom and left. Could that be what is keeping the width around 2.21 and the height around 6.9?

Comment: i couldn't reproduce your issue... so i uploaded test project [here](http://www.rupan.net/uploader/download/1420801301.zip). please download it and run.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, I thin that link is bad, I get a "Not Found, The requested URL /uploader/ was not found on this server." error. I've also uploaded a test project showing my issue [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18781527/CollectionViewTest.zip)

Comment: Found your project on your site's homepage and it works great. Noticed that my version was using indexPath.row, not indexPath.item like you are. This improved the issue, I need to add about 30 pixels to the width to not truncate the label, as you do in your example. Thanks for the help.

Comment: sorry for the link. it seems that calculated string-size is not equal to the actual string-size which label draws. so we need to fix the difference.